# Programming an Event listener for files in a directory on Linux

Tags: c#, java, python, linux, event-handling

On Ubuntu linux, when you watch a flash video, it gets saved temporarily in the /tmp as flv files while the video buffers. I use vlc to directly play these files.

Currently, I have scripted a shortcut that directly scans and opens the latest file in /tmp with vlc, when clicked.

But, I want to program a Java application that will continually monitor this /tmp directory for any new flv files, and open it in vlc automatically. I know I can use Runtime.exec() to open the VLC application with the flv files. But, I DO NOT want to run a while(true) loop (with sleep) to scan for files.

How can I make use of Event Handling (Java or any other language) on Linux to complete this task?

Edit:
I am also wondering if Java is the right way to approach this. As someone suggested below, Python and QT seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python, use pyinotify: http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify.  It's a simple, standalone library; there's no need for an ugly Qt dependency for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) ? It's a Java library that uses OS-specific code to listen for filesystem events.

I wouldn't rule out polling the file system, however, unless you're dealing with a huge number of files/directories.

Comment: I'll certainly have a look. By the way, isn't polling via while(true) considered to be a bad practice? There are only half a dozen files to monitor. I am also wondering if Java is a suitable language for this purpose.

Comment: I think polling can be a pragmatic solution, so long as you're not polling so hard as to affect your disk performance. Polling (say) once a second won't impact your system to any noticeable degree.

Comment: It will if there happen to be a lot of other files in /tmp.

Comment: Can you qualify how many ? I would expect performance to degrade when you have thousands of files (perhaps 10s of thousands).

Answer (score 1):

In Linux there something called FAM (File Alteration Monitor) which does a better job than the sleep/poll thing.
There's a python package for it as well: [Python FAM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-fam/)

It is probably going to be a lot less to depend on than for example QT.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Qt and Python.

I've used PyQt for a similar project before.  Qt has a file system watcher that monitors directories and files for updates, which trigger events that you can catch and do stuff (like open vlc).

[QFileSystemWatcher](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfilesystemwatcher.html)

If this is something you just want to always run in the background, Qt also has a feature that allows you to run your program in the System Tray.  This is what I did, and just added a menu or two to make modifications.

[QSystemTrayIcon](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsystemtrayicon.html)

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I have minimum experience with PyQt, but am interested to try it out. Are there any resources/books that you would like to recommend from your experience?

Comment: A Qt dependency just to monitor file events would be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, you can try this [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576377-high-level-inotify-wrapper/), I find it simpler than pyinotify.